# 2007 Altima - Dash lights and automatic acceleration when starting

Tags: starting, nissan, lights, altima, dash

Sometimes when starting my car several dash lights go on and off as the engine revs up and down several times. If the car is put in drive before the car starts revving up and down then the car will automatically accelerate a little. The battery has been replaced but did not help. Tests for the alternator (done by the dealer) show it running fine, at least after the car starts. [See this video of the car starting for specifics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOvChtWw4X0)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you replace a battery in a nissan that has an electronic throttle body, you must perform a throttle body relearn procedure. Did you do that? If not, you'll wind up with a surging idle since it no longer remembers the home position.

Comment: The dealer replaced the battery in an attempt to fix this issue so I hope they did what was needed. The battery I had before was at least a few years old and I know a throttle body relearn procedure was not performed after it was installed.